# Decreasing Distance Between Column Names

Tags: multicolumn, booktabs

This is my first time using TEX. After getting a lot of help from this site, I could not find this exact question.

I want to decrease the gap between my first two column titles.

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Title 1}
\begin{tabular}{rlllllll}
\toprule
& a  & Was this  & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Average MuchLonger Name Goes Here:}  \\
\cmidrule(){4-8}

& a &  Identified by You? & C & D & E & F & G\\ 
\midrule
& 5\% & 12.9\% & 7.3281 & 7.2445 & 2.1601 & 4.3438 & 4.2821 \\ 
&   &   & (.4038) & (.5058) & (.9049) & (.9032) & (.8831) \\ 

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

After running this code I get the following Table:

[image]

Question: Is it possible to decrease the gap for the first two column titles? I would like those values to be right on top of each other if possible, or at least a bit closer to one another.

Appreciate it.

Comment: I am new to this so perhaps? Am I able to specify that for columns 1 & 2 only?

Comment: @HenriMenke : this will decrease the distance between the lines of the table, not the columns?!

Comment: Sorry I was wondering if it was at all possible to smash the titles in Col 1 & 2 ONLY. So minimizing the distance between a & a, and then "Was this" and "Identified By You?".

Comment: I will try it out though! Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  You are looking for `\begin{tabular}{r@{\hskip5pt}lllllll}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, you should know, that LaTeX will always insert a gap between two columns.  In fact, it will increase the length `\tabcolsep` (respectively `\arraycolsep` in mathetical arrays) before and after each column. Having said that, you may want to get rid of the extra separation space in front of the first column and after the last column.  They are not needed there.  After all: what do you want to separate from the first column?

PLease load the package array `\usepackage{array}` in the preamble.  Having it loaded, you can define your table declaration as follows
    \begin{tabular}{@{}rlllllll@{}}

Those `@{}` will remove the unnecessary space.

Second, you are using `r` and `l` column definitions in your tabular.  This will result in  automatically increasing columnwidths.  LaTeX will calculate the width of each column in such, that is able to fill the content of one cell.  In your example, the header text "Identified by You?" is the longest cell entry in the second column.  Hence, the second column will formatted by LaTeX, that this entry will fit.

In my opinion, you have two choices: either you reduce the font size a bit, thereby reducing the overall width of this column accordingly.  Or you decide to rotate the header by 90°.

BTW: You do have an empty column as first column in your example.  In my example, I removed this empty column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllllll@{}}
  \toprule
  &  & \multicolumn{5}{c@{}}{Average MuchLonger Name Goes Here:}  \\
  \cmidrule(){3-7}
   a & \rotatebox{90}{\parbox{2cm}{Was this\\ Identified by You?}}& C & D & E & F & G\\ 
  \midrule
   5\% & 12.9\% & 7.3281 & 7.2445 & 2.1601 & 4.3438 & 4.2821 \\ 
     &   & (.4038) & (.5058) & (.9049) & (.9032) & (.8831) \\ 
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Here is its output
[image]

Is this more appealing to you?

One more suggestion: maybe you should add "a" and "Was this\ Identified by You?" into the first line of the table.

The example reads now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllllll@{}}
  \toprule
  a &  \rotatebox{90}{\parbox{2cm}{Was this\\ Identified by You?}} 
    & \multicolumn{5}{c@{}}{Average MuchLonger Name Goes Here:}  \\
  \cmidrule(){3-7}
    & & C & D & E & F & G\\ 
  \midrule
   5\% & 12.9\% & 7.3281 & 7.2445 & 2.1601 & 4.3438 & 4.2821 \\ 
     &   & (.4038) & (.5058) & (.9049) & (.9032) & (.8831) \\ 
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And the output looks like this

[image]

Have fun

Jan

Comment: Your second suggestion makes a lot of sense. Did not realize I could rotate! Helpful!

Comment: @Mico thank you, you are so right.  I corrected and added it.